# What is the trick to entering an address in a format string exploit without pipe capabilities?

Tags: c#, security, format-string

Note: This is for educational use only. The program in question is for my Applied Security class and was designed to have a format string vulnerability.

The scenario on the assignment is inserting shell code on a server of an evil regime. Although my question here is only how to store an address when I can't use pipe capabilities to insert hex values into the original string outside of the ASCII range.

The format string vulnerable part of the program asks for input and is only accessible through a few options inside of the program.

How do you store an address in the original string? The source code of the format string vulnerable program is hidden. I cannot pipe into the vulnerable string since the vulnerable string is embedded in the program.

I am currently trying the following input by copying and pasting it into the program:

```
\xea\xff\xff\xbf %x%x%x%x%x%x%x |%x|
```

Which gives the following result:

```
\xea\xff\xff\xbf 805d1c01234567808060f206bffff67c123456786165785c |6666785c|
```

It appears to read one character at a time. I know the next step with %d and %n to change the value at an address.

Should I try to store the address elsewhere? Is there some trick to input characters outside of the ASCII range? What should I consider to try to store an address properly? There is a trick to this but I just don't know it.

Comment: poster is trying to stuff something into a string  that wasn't designed by the program to be processed in this manner.  The Format String exploit occurs when the submitted data of an input string is evaluated as a command by the application. In this way, the attacker could execute code, read the stack, or cause a segmentation fault in the running application, causing new behaviors that could compromise the security or the stability of the system

Comment: That is true. This is for my security class.

Comment: I still have no clue what the goal of the exercise is. Please add a few *paragraphs* explaining what you are doing, what the final goal is, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Alright but my main question is how can I store an address in the original string? I only know how to store characters in the Ascii range which doesn't give me hex values greater than 7F. If I store an address in the original string, then I can change the value at that address with %d and %n.

Comment: I don't get how this would work in C# at all. C#'s `string.Format` allocates a new result string of the correct size. Contrary to c where you need to be careful about buffer sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! You couldn't enter an address there. I had to utilize an address that I found and I used it to change a variable that determined if I could use other functions. I used those functions to redirect the program flow to shell code. Although my teacher reset the control variable every time I used it so I had to keep changing it back to experiment with the new functions.